# Kafka Producer - multiple topics

Tags: apache-kafka

I have to make sure that based on a request from a consumer, a new topic is created and a new producer is assigned to it who has to take the name of the topic and use them to add information to the topic. How can I do this?

I expect each producer to be associated with a single topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Topics must exist for consumer to subscribe to.

If you want to have any coupling between consumers and producers, you'll need an external datastore for that, since Kafka is designed for them to be decoupled